# Html/Css adding elements to div causes div to get pushed

Tags: html, css

I trying to add dynamic elements into to the div.
Div has `height:auto`, but if something added to div its get scaled but its gets pushed too.

Causing this:
["Correct one on small data"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ORU.png)
[Issue if data is big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxlqI.png)

```
    <div style="margin-left:355px;  background: linear-gradient(55deg, rgba(46,46,45,1) 0%, rgba(37,37,37,1) 100%); width:700px;  display:block; height:auto;  position:absolute;  vertical-align:top; display:inline-block; overflow: hidden;  " class="formedt tdform">
<div style="position:sticky;" class="formtd tdform">
    Status
</div>
    <?php
    $stattable = dbt("statusses");
    foreach($stattable as $status){
        $statusdt = $status['status'];
    ?>
<div style="position: relative;  background:linear-gradient(55deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 30%) 0%, rgb(17 17 17 / 98%) 100%); height:55px;">
    <?php echo  $statusdt; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I tried lots of stuff on internet but i cant find any info about this.

Comment: You should probably tell us what the CSS classes `formedt tdform` do, but try removing `vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;` and setting the `top` and `left` properties to move the containing div to where you always want it to be.

Comment: formedt is class that is box shado i added these due i found these for fixing this but they didnt helped

Answer (score 0):

Set `position: absolute;`:

```
<div style="position: absolute;  background:linear-gradient(55deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 30%) 0%, rgb(17 17 17 / 98%) 100%); height:55px;">
    <?php echo  $statusdt; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

If you add it, it will move only when the [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) moves, if ever.